# outputting a c# variable to a aspx textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

i'm simply trying to display a variable from the back end of an eform into a textbox on the front end, here's what i have so far.

.aspx.cs

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  string username = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];   
}
```

and in .aspx im trying to output the variable like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" Width="44px" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%username %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask  -- in your other questions, you actually comment that the answer was helpful but neither upvoted the response nor accepted the answer.  Following the rules here will yield a much better experience.

Comment: thank you, will adjust my tactics

Comment: Thanks Everyone for the help, looks like the real problem was not with my syntax but where I was placing it. was placing it in the protected page load on the aspx.cs and not the aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make username a public/protected class member and change .aspx line to below-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username1" runat="server" Width="44px" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%= username %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

you need to use <%= var name %>
and change text box name because you cant have two same name variable in class....

Answer (score 1):

```
username.Text = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
```

Should do it.  But you really ought to Google this.